# How to get id from @username using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna build mention and notification in my website. But I don't have any idea how to relate these 2 tables. Or can I combine these 2 tables become 1 table.
So if subj_id(sender) mention one or some obj_id(recipients)so it will be saved into tb_notif and mention.

```
tb_notif
--------
id_notif
id_mention
type   
descrip

tb_mention
----------
id_mention
subj_id
obj_id
Status(Read/Unread)
```

> e.g input : hey what's up @user1, @user2, @user3 ?
>
> e.g input : Long time no see?

**I don't know how to get the id of @user1, @user2, @user3 and save them in obj_id.**

```
id_notif    subj_id    obj_id   id_post     type       mention     descrip
1             4          1         1        comment     yes         hey what's up @user1, @user2, @user3 ?
2             2          5         1        comment      no         Long time no see.
```

**
if there's mention(yes) so it will save every @user(obj_id) in obj_id**

```
id_mention   id_notif    subj_id   obj_id    status
1               1            4        1         Read
2               1            4        2         Unread
3               1            4        3         Unread
```

Comment: sorry but where is your user id I couldn't see in tables ?

Comment: I've edited it. user id->obj_id

Comment: can you pls share php code too?